# Android: FragmentPagerAdapter not working with ViewPager and material TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am setting up a `ViewPager` which will render fragments depending of the selected tab in a `TabLayout` from material. I have a fragment which will be rendering all of this as the parent view (Which i don't know if this could be the cause.), and i am doing all this flow because i would like to set the data flow to be like `Master Detail flow` in which an activity will show 2 fragments, one of this will have a pager that displays another fragment in a `ViewPager`

So the fragment that has both the `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` have the class defined like this:

```
public class InstructionsFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = InstructionsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private TabLayout instructionsTab;
    private ViewPager instructionsPager;

    private int recipeIndex;

    public InstructionsFragment(int recipeIndex) {
        this.recipeIndex = recipeIndex;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_instructions, container, false);

        this.loadViews(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        this.loadPager();
    }

    private void loadViews(View view) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading views");

        this.instructionsTab = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_instructions_tabs);
        this.instructionsPager = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_instructions_pager);

        this.instructionsTab.setupWithViewPager(this.instructionsPager);
    }

    private void loadPager() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading pager");

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();
        IngredientsFragment ingredientsFragment = new IngredientsFragment(recipeIndex);

        InstructionsPagerAdapter instructionsAdapter = new InstructionsPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, 0);
        instructionsAdapter.addFragment(ingredientsFragment);

        this.instructionsPager.setAdapter(instructionsAdapter);
    }
```

This fragment makes use of the layout defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/instructions_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipe_instructions_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/recipe_detail_tab_ingredients_label" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/recipe_detail_tab_steps_label" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/recipe_instructions_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So there's basically 2 static tabs and i want to test with just one, because even when i delete one of the tabs it still doesn't work.

The `FragmentPagerAdater` is defined in a class like this:

```
public class InstructionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public InstructionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragments.add(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

When going to the activity which displayes the `InstructionsFragment`, The tabs for some reason are not displaying and neither is the fragment selected by default. I did make some debugging in to see if there's an error or if the selected fragment by the viewPager is running, and i don't see any error logs in `logcat` and the selected fragment is actually running, so i don't know how to continue.

This is how the screen is displaying all of the code i've implemented:
[image: Image loading the pager]

And this is how it looks without loading the pager code:
[image: Image without loading the pager code]

I am running the application on `Android 9` and these are the dependencies in my project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: instead of passing getFragmentManager into your adapter, try passing getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: @JRowan Same effect

Comment: move setupwithviewpager to after when you set the adapter

Comment: @JRowan Same result

Comment: I wish I could post code in a comment, how I have mine is I set up the adapter in the onCreate method of fragment class and then I do everything else in onCreateView, ill post it as an answer so you can see even though it may not work

Comment: let e know if my answer below works, if not ill still try to help you diagnose what's wrong

Comment: also I just noticed I'm using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Comment: Your example still didn't work for me, but i think it might have something to do with adding static tabs instead of adding them dynamically, i will try to do this by adding them dynamically and will let you know what came up with it

Comment: yeah I don't have static tabs, I add labels in my adapter and keep them in a list and then I override the get page title methid I just added the code for that

Comment: @JRowan i was able to make it work, it looks like `TabLayout` material component does not support having static defined tabs when using an Adapter.. I will create an answer showing how i was able to make it work

Comment: @JRowan Well, i was partially able to make it work, what i didn't realize is that the fragment is still not rendering..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by adding tabs dynamically, it looks like `TabsLayout` from material doesn't support having a static set of tabs in layout while using a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` must have an adapter which feeds the title of the tab for the selected fragment to display in the `ViewPager`.

The end code for the `FragmentPagerAdapter` looks like this:

```
public class InstructionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> pageTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public InstructionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String tabTitle) {
        this.fragments.add(fragment);
        this.pageTitles.add(tabTitle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return this.pageTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Adding a list of titles for the fragments and select it when a fragment is selected.

Answer (score 0):

since I cannot post code in a comment here is how I am doing the same thing and it works in a fragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new PickPowerballTickets(), getResources().getString(R.string.powerball));
        adapter.addFragment(new PickMegaMillionsTickets(), getResources().getString(R.string.megamillions));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pick_my_tickets, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }
```

here is my pager adapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```